# Spinner#setDropDownVerticalOffset for API lower 16

Tags: android, android-view, android-spinner

I'm using `Spinner` and I have an issue that `setDropDownVerticalOffset()` solves perfectly, but my min api level is 14 and method's min required is 16.

How to use that method for APIs lower 16?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatSpinner.html) instead of [`android.widget.Spinner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html).